# Having a Main() routine in a separate file from a Class in C#

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-express

I recently branched out into C# written with Visual Studio Express from C++ written with gVIM. I've been told I'll have to unlearn a lot of stuff to really use C# effectively, but here's my question:

In C++ when writing a class or data type, I would have separate files for the class definition and the driver program. I would then `#include` the class in the driver program in order to use it. It isn't terribly clear how to do this in Visual Studio Express 2013 and all the tutorials I've looked up have the class definition and the Main() routine in the same file.

I currently have only two files in my solution folder: the driver program **p1.cs** and the type definition/implementation **targetInt.cs**. What is the best way to allow **p1.cs** to work with my **targetInt.cs** type? Will it simply have access by virtue of being part of the same solution? If so, how to I get around not having a Main() routine in my type definition?

Here is a screenshot of the solution and the error I'm getting when I try to build the solution. I don't get an error for trying to declare a `targetInt` object in **p1.cs** which points to the namespace already being shared.

http://i793.photobucket.com/albums/yy218/tombombodil/solution_zps6a743e2d.png

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: From your screenshot: your `p1.cs` file (where you `Main` lives) isn't even part of the same project! You've put it in the solution, but not in the project. Move it into the project and then import the namespace from `targetInit` with `using targetInit.cs`.

Comment: Your classes should share the namespace. You usually have one namespace per project, and they usually have project-related names, instead of a file.extension format. With your code as it is now, you should have to write `targetInt.cs.targetInt int1 = new targetInt.cs.targetInt();`. All files that will tightly work together should belong to the same project. Think of a project as a dll.

Comment: @MattBurland I think that might be the crux of it. Still trying to figure out VS. It's about as different from VIM as it is possible to be.

Comment: @user3776749: NP. It's always difficult moving to a new environment and you inevitably end up fighting it and trying to make it work like the old one until it *clicks* for you.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not terribly complicated, but it is different from C++. So if you have one file that looks something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        //...stuff
    }
}
```

And then you want another file with your `Main` (which you will for anything more than a trivially simple project), it would look something like this:

```
using MyNamespace;   // unless you use the same namespace for both

namespace SomeOtherNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new MyClass();
            // alternatively, without the using statement, you can just fully qualify 
            // your class name like so:
            // var c = new MyNamespace.MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

But do note that the files need to be *in the same project*. If they are in different projects you can still do it, but you have to add a reference to the project with `MyClass` to the project with `Program`. What you can't do is just have an orphaned C# file floating around in your solution and expect it to work.

Comment: This cleared it up for me. Thanks for the clear and complete explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The problem as you've written boils down to the simple lack of shared namespaces - because `targetInit` exists in a separate namespace, `Program` needs a `using  targetInit.cs` to access the `targetInit` type. They can, however, access each other by virtue of being in the same *project* - a Solution can contain multiple Projects, and if they don't reference each other, they can't access each other's types.

Usually, the `naemspace` of any given class is actually the folder path to it, and the class name is the same as the file name (which Visual Studio does for you when you make new class files).

As for the `Main()` definition, you only want one of these since you only have a single entry point for the system to jump to when your program begins - having multiple `Main()` functions doesn't make much sense when the OS needs a clear place to begin  execution.

The `Main()` method and class definitions sitting in the same file is a convenience so all the code can be read together - to get an idea for how actual projects are set up, trying going to GitHub and forking a couple of open-source projects.

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches to use another class in C# directly:
1-putting that class in the same namespace of my class(even if they were in separate files), this code clarify this:

```
//file TargetInt.cs
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class TargetInt
    {
    }
}  
//file p1.cs
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class p1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

notice that both classes are in MyNameSpace namespace.
2-if the other class is contained within another namespace, you can simply use it by declaring this statement in the upper beginning of the file:

```
//file TargetInt.cs
namespace OtherNameSpace
{
    class TargetInt
    {
    }
}
//file p1.cs
using OtherNameSpace;
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class p1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

with `using OtherNameSpace;` you can use TargetInt class directly.